# Show that the ring of formal power series is a Euclidean domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, localization, formal-power-series, euclidean-domain

Here is the question I want to solve part $(c)$ of it:

A commutative ring $R$ is local if it has a unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}.$ In this case, we say $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ is a local ring. For example, if $R$ is a field, then $(R,(0))$ is a local ring, since the only proper ideal of a field is $(0).$

$(a)$ Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring. Show that $R^* = R\setminus \mathfrak{m}.$

$(b)$ Show that, for a field $K,$ $R = K[[x]]$ is a local ring.

$(c)$ Show that $R = K[[x]]$ is a Euclidean domain.

I got hint to use that $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring but I still do not know how to do that, could anyone help me in this proof please?

**Euclidean Domain definition:**

A euclidean domain $R$ is an integral domain together with a function $\sigma : R \rightarrow \mathbb N$  where $\sigma (r) = 0 \iff r= 0 $ (well ordered monoid) and such that, for each $a,b \in R,$ there exist $q,r \in R$ where $a = bq + r$ and $\sigma(r) < \sigma(b).$

Comment: Try to think of what characterizes invertible power series and also recall the notion of *order* of one indeterminate power series.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ can you give me the details please in an answer?

Comment: Bernard has given you solid hints as to how the final answer should look like.Being rather busy these days I am afraid I can't oblige with a methodically laid out answer of my own (which is why I only approached you in the comment section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use as a *Euclidean function* $\sigma$ the order of a formal power series:
$$\sigma(a_0+a_1X+a_2X^2+\dots)=\min\{i\in\mathbf N\mid a_i\ne 0\}$$
and prove the existence of $q$ and $r$ by comparing the orders of the dividend $f$ and divisor $g$.

*Some details*:

Let $f,g\in K[[X]]$ and $\sigma(g)=r$.

1. If $\sigma(f)<\sigma(g)$, the solution is obvious: $q=0$, $\:r=f$.
2. If  $\sigma(f)\ge\sigma(g)$, I'll give  an example: suppose $\:f=X^3(X^2+2X^3+3X^4+4X^5+\dots)\:$ and  $g=X^3+X^4+X^5=X^3(1+X+X^2)$ (a polynomial is also a formal power series). Note that $u=1+X+X^2$ is a unit in $K[[X]]$, which is a discrete valuation ring. We deduce that
   \begin{align}
   f&=(X^2+2X^3+3X^4+4x^5+\dots)X^3\\
   &=\underbrace{(X^2+2X^3+3X^4+4x^5+\dots)u^{-1}\!}_{\textstyle q}\;g,
   \end{align}

Comment: Can you show me the details please? I do not see what you said.

Comment: @Confusion: I've added some details. Is it clearer?

Comment: Ok I will read it and answer you within 4.5 hours.

Comment: how did we use the hint that we have a local ring ?

Comment: @Confusion: my explanation wasn't good (messed up with another problem I had in mind). I've modified it; and now it should be clear (I hope) where we use that we have a local (more precisely a D.V.R.). ring